# AngularJS - How configure $routeProvider after library update to 1.2?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

With the 1.0.4 version my code works, but with the 1.2.x not anymore.

my javascript

```
demoApp.config(function($routeProvider){

$routeProvider.
   when("/",{
        contrller: simpleController,
        templateUrl: "view2.htm",
   }).
   when("/second",{
        controller: simpleController,
        templateUrl: "view2.htm"
   }).
       when("/tird",{
        controller: simpleController,
        templateUrl: "view3.htm"
   }).
   otherwise({redirectTo: "/second"});

});
```

Answer (score 2):

`$routeProvider` is no longer included in updated versions of Angular. You have to include `angular-route.js` if you want to continue using it.